# How do I decide on supra-supra/supra-antara and thermally/photochemically when the educt and product of the sigmatropic rearrangment is given?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic

Was the given product of this [1,5]-sigmatropic rearrangement reached thermally with orbitals suprafacial-suprafacial or photochemically with orbitals suprafacial-antarafacial?

[image]

The same question goes for this Claisen-rearrangement:
[image]

I would think both a thermal reaction where orbitals meet suprafacial-suprafacial and a photochemical reaction where orbitals meet suprafacial-antarafacial is possible as neither educts nor products are stereospecific. I am supposed to choose one though, which confuses me. Am I missing something? I hope you can help, as I do not know where else to look anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first is tautomerisation - why should it have anything to do with sigmatropic?